# Close keyboard when opening tab on a single click

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator

I want to close the keyboard when the user clicks a particular tab.

What's happening now is that when the keyboard is open and the user wants to switch to another tab, he must close/minimize the keyboard first.

The prop on a `ScrollView` `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` does what I want, but only for a `ScrollView`, not for a `TabNavigator` component.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function to hide the keyboard and call it from `onClick` of that tab.
 
This is the function you should declare in the same class in which `onClick` of that tab exists.

```
@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
    public void hideKeyBoard(View view){
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),0);    
    }
```

And then from the `onClick`, just call this by using `hideKeyBoard();`.
This will hide the keyboard whenever that tab is tapped.
And You should provide some of your code if seeking help.